# Oracle help: Dynamic choose t-5 to t-1 days average data

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select distinct trunc(a,'dd') day,
avg(g) over ( order by trunc(a,'dd') RANGE between 5 preceding and current row ) a1
from( 
select to_date(concat(concat(a,' '),b),'yyyymmdd hh24mi') a,  A1SPREAD21.c, A1SPREAD21.d,
 A1SPREAD21.e, A1SPREAD21.f,A1SPREAD21.g, A1SPREAD21.h, A1SPREAD21.i, A1SPREAD21.j
from  A1SPREAD21) t1
order by 1
```

SQL code is listed as above. but unfortunately, I want to calculate 5 days average data daynamically, such as on T day, I want to use T-5 to T-1 interval data.  so will someone help?

table

```
20100419    1034    IF1005  IF1006  3361.60 3388.60 -27     4695    527 316 24
20100419    1035    IF1005  IF1006  3365    3392.20 -27.20  4713    530 402 23
20100419    1036    IF1005  IF1006  3366    3392.80 -26.80  4722    527 408 16
20100419    1037    IF1005  IF1006  3367    3394    -27     4682    533 454 35
20100419    1038    IF1005  IF1006  3366.40 3395    -28.60  4741    529 301 28
20100419    1039    IF1005  IF1006  3366.40 3395    -28.60  4770    530 179 17
```

**edit:**
data is deposit on dropbox, xlsx fromat
https://www.dropbox.com/s/67y8mm0gims96us/a1spread21.xlsx

```
select avg(g) 
from  A1SPREAD21 
where a between 20110101 and 20110110
```

result is
-27.00, and the sql could give 20110111 data -27.00.

what I want is every trading day(can get in the table， not as calendar day) getting previous t-5 to t-1 average.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the clause should be this one:

```
avg(g) over (order by a RANGE between NUMTODSINTERVAL(5, 'day') PRECEDING
AND NUMTODSINTERVAL(1, 'day') PRECEDING)
```

Comment: It's not the result I want. I check it, and  the data I want is daily frequency, so first the time window is T-5 day to T-1 day, which period contains much data, more than 1000 number.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct trunc(a,'dd') day,
avg(g) over ( order by trunc(a,'dd') RANGE between 6 preceding and 1 preceding ) a1
from( 
select to_date(concat(concat(a,' '),b),'yyyymmdd hh24mi') a,  A1SPREAD21.c, A1SPREAD21.d,
 A1SPREAD21.e, A1SPREAD21.f,A1SPREAD21.g, A1SPREAD21.h, A1SPREAD21.i, A1SPREAD21.j
from  A1SPREAD21) t1
order by 1
```

Did testing over

```
SELECT DISTINCT TRUNC ( a, 'dd' ) DAY,
  AVG ( g ) OVER ( ORDER BY TRUNC ( A, 'dd' ) RANGE BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND
  1 preceding ) a1, g 
   FROM
  (
     SELECT sysdate - 10  a,  1 as g from dual union all
     SELECT SYSDATE - 5 ,  3  FROM dual UNION ALL
     SELECT SYSDATE - 3 ,  45 FROM dual UNION ALL
     SELECT SYSDATE - 6 ,  56 FROM dual UNION ALL
     SELECT SYSDATE - 7 ,  23 FROM dual UNION ALL
     SELECT sysdate - 8 ,  67 from dual union all
     SELECT sysdate - 2 ,  7 from dual union all
     SELECT SYSDATE - 1 ,  8 FROM dual UNION ALL
     SELECT sysdate - 4 ,  541 from dual
  )
  t1
ORDER BY 1
```

Output

```
|                             DAY |              A1 |   G |
|---------------------------------|-----------------|-----|
| December, 29 2013 00:00:00+0000 |          (null) |   1 |
| December, 31 2013 00:00:00+0000 |               1 |  67 |
|  January, 01 2014 00:00:00+0000 |              34 |  23 |
|  January, 02 2014 00:00:00+0000 | 30.333333333333 |  56 |
|  January, 03 2014 00:00:00+0000 |           36.75 |   3 |
|  January, 04 2014 00:00:00+0000 |              30 | 541 |
|  January, 05 2014 00:00:00+0000 |             138 |  45 |
|  January, 06 2014 00:00:00+0000 |           122.5 |   7 |
|  January, 07 2014 00:00:00+0000 |           112.5 |   8 |
```

Comment: it's not right. the data contains A B column, which format is like yyyymmdd and hh24mi. I need to give a result on every T day, which calculate from T-5 to T-1 day.

Comment: I have modified the post with my test data and it worked for me.

Comment: OK, so you want 5 days data, it means you window lies between t-6 and t-1. Modified original again.

Comment: no, the result is not correct. I use the code select avg(g) from  A1SPREAD21 where a between 20110101 and 20110110 to compare the result. 20110101 and 20110110 have 5  trading days.

Comment: Well, you must choose a window of 6 days in that case, because you will get the average of last five days on sixth day, other wise you will get average of last 4 days only on the last day. Your where condition provides only 5 rows to the avg() analytical function, as such you will get average of last 1 day on 2nd day, last 2 days on 3rd day and so on until 6th day is reached, then after you will start getting results as expected.

Comment: 2011-01-01 to 2011-01-10 are 9 days not 5 (or 6). In your opening question you did not mention anything about trading days or weekends!

Comment: but the result will have some imperefct, suppose I have five days, every day have three data,get an average. if on five days, everyday have a average, this result will not like the whole average.

Comment: oh, yes. I don't mention it. I suppose T is trading days.

Comment: Still your original question is not clear, is it like you want to take average of all the data present on a particular day and then apply above logic to get t-5 to t-1 average? Specify with proper example. There is solution to every requirement but the minimum expectation is proper explanation of the requirement.

Comment: en, yes. everyday get previous  t-5 to t-1 average

Answer (score 0):

try this one (testtable is, of course, only for testing):

```
with testtable as (
  select date '2013-01-08' a,1 g from dual union all
  select date '2013-01-02' a,2 g from dual union all
  select date '2013-01-05' a,3 g from dual union all
  select date '2013-01-07' a,4 g from dual
)
select distinct trunc(a,'dd') day,
                avg(g) over(order by a rows between (select count(*)
                                                     from testtable tin
                                                     where trunc(a,'dd') between trunc(t.a,'dd') - 5 and trunc(t.a,'dd') - 1) preceding and current row) a1
from testtable t
order by 1
```

I used sum() instead of average to check, because average is quite difficult to test fast, but for sure it works.

I am not sure about this requirement of you `trunc(t.a,'dd') - 1`, maybe you wish to remove -1?

See [Oracle windowing functions description](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/img_text/windowing_clause.htm) to learn more about it.

Comment: Because every day have many data, so I have a idea to give every 5 days mean data, so trunc(t.a,'dd') - 1 means the nearest 1 day.

Comment: Ok, anyway the question is about how to calculate the amount of preceding rows :) everything else is your choice

Comment: Edited the query: range replaced with rows

Comment: a lot time passed, but the code didnt give result, now still run. so I think the code maybe not effective.

Comment: <pre>with testtable as (
  select date '2013-01-08 01:01:00' a,1 g from dual union all
  select date '2013-01-08 01:02:00' a,2 g from dual union all
  select date '2013-01-07 01:03:00' a,3 g from dual
)
select distinct trunc(a,'dd') day,
                avg(g) over(order by a rows between (select count(*)
                                                     from testtable tin
                                                     where trunc(a,'dd') between trunc(t.a,'dd') - 5 and trunc(t.a,'dd') - 1) preceding and current row) a1
from testtable t
order by 1 <code>  this code is not take effect.